# Prove that is base of topology and is a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

I have problems with this exercise:

For any pair of integers $a,b \in N= \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Define the sets:

$N_{a,b} = \{ a+kb: k \in {\mathbb{Z}}_{\geq{0} }  \} \subset{N} $

Let $(a,b)$ greatest common divisor. Prove that set $\mathbb{B} = \{ N_{a,b} : a,b \in N,(a,b) =1 \}$ is a basis of a topology and $(N,N_{a,b})$ is a Hausdorff space

I have to prove that :

Let $X$ be a set and $\Bbb B \subset P(X)$ a family of subsets. There exists a topology on $X$ for which $\Bbb B$ is a basis if and only if two conditions hold:

1. $X= \cup \{ B| B \in \mathbb{B}\}$
2. For any pair $A,B \in \mathbb{B} $ and any point $x \in  A \cap B$ there exist $C \in \mathbb{B}$ such that $x \in C \subset{A\cap{B}}$

Comment: That last fact is known right? It’s a separate fact and usually part of the main text in a course (it’s in Munkres e.g.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $a \in \Bbb Z$, note that $a \in N_{a,1} = \{z \in \Bbb Z\mid z \ge a\}$ and the latter set is in $\Bbb B$ as $(a,1)=1$. So condition 1 for being a base is satisfied.

If $c \in N_{a,b} \cap N_{a’,b’}$, then $c = a+k_1b = a’+k_2b’$ for some $k_1,k_2$ positive integers. Let $b’’=(b’,b’’)$ and note that $c \in N_{a,b’’} \subseteq N_{a,b} \cap N_{a’,b’}$ and clearly $(b’’,a) \le (b,a)=1$ so condition 2 is satisfied too.

That the space is Hausdorff is clear: if $n \neq m$ in $\Bbb Z$ let $p$ be any prime that does not divide $n-m$ nor $n$ nor $m$, and note that $n \in N_{n,p}, m \in N_{m,p}, N_{n,p} \cap N_{m,p}=\emptyset$ showing $X$ is Hausdorff.